# Wordpress - Images not showing up in the Media Library

Tags: wordpress, media-library

I have a huge problem with my Wordpress. My uploaded images don't list in the Media Library.

It is weird tho, it says I have 75 images, but display none. Take a look yourself.

[image: 75 images, none list]

Even weirder, if I go into gallery (the images you uploaded in the page itself), the images list just fine.

I already tried deactivating all my plugins, didn't work. Cache can be easily put out of the question, because it happened on at least 4 different computers, with Macs, PCs, and navigating with Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

Another interesting fact is that if I upload the image directly trough the computer (with the "From Computer" tab), everything goes fine. Another website on the same server works just fine too. And just to add to the complexity, when I go to the media page in the Wordpress Admin, all images show up just fine.

Oh, and before I forget... applying any filters, or doing a research in the media will always come up with the same problem.

So there... that's where I'm at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you upload those images; via FTP or through WP uploader? You have to upload images THROUGH WP uploader in order to show them in the image library.

Comment: Yes, I did upload the images via WPUploader.

Comment: What is your wordpress version? You just upgraded wordpress or it is clean install? Can you list all of your active and inactive plugin?

Comment: It was an updated version... Check my answer for more details.

Comment: So you figured it out! You can also use this plugin if it is not fixed yet:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hotfix/

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I am uploading photos that are retrieved from webserices, but it does not show them , although the photos will be saves successfully, any idea?

Answer (score 11):

I had a same problem just now, with missing media library images for my blog. The images appeared to be right there in the media library and were definitely on the actual web server (checked via FTP).

As Allen Z advised I did "check Settings → Media and make sure that Uploading Files folder is set to wp-content/uploads"

Mine were set to the default blank. ***I altered this to an absolute path http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads***

THIS DIDNT SOLVE THE PROBLEM when I refreshed the site in browser. However, I immediately changed the path back to blank (the default setting again) and everything came back! Woop

Everyone having this problem might want to try this before getting into the more technical fixes!

Comment: Clearing my absolute URL worked for me, too! Thanks Tony!

Comment: Just had this problem now. It was the database that was corrupted. After repairing the database through cPanel the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 8):

it was your permalinks...  you must have changed to labeled-name... switch back to default.

that worked for me.

Comment: Do you have any idea how resetting the permalinks can cause the images to reappear again?

Answer (score 7):

Check Screen Options (dropdown tab in the upper right hand corner of the page), and make sure there are sane settings for what to show on screen. All the column settings should be checked, and there should be a positive number of media items being shown on screen.

If that is ok, then check Settings → Media and make sure that Uploading Files folder is set to `wp-content/uploads`.

I believe these are the only settings that can be changed from the administrative screens.

Comment: I checked these up, everything seems fine... nothing in screen options seems off and in media settings, the store uploads in this folder field is empty, going to the default wp-content/uploads

Comment: Try checking `wp-content/uploads` in the actual server filesystem, to verify that your images are indeed being stored there.

Answer (score 6):

Here's something a guy on Wordpress forum showed us. Add the following to your functions.php file. (remember to create a backup of your functions.php first)

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );
function change_graphic_lib($array) {
  return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```

...it was that simple.

Answer (score 5):

Well, Seems like there was a bug when creating custom post types in the function.php file of the theme... which bugged that.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem with wordpress 3.8.1 and it turned out that my functions.php wasn't saved as utf-8. Re-saved it and it

Answer (score 4):

I faced same issue on my wordpress site. After the lot of debugging i fixed my problem step by step like this.

1. First add given below code your db-config.php

> ```
> define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', TRUE);
> define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE);
> define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
> ```

2. Then goto /wp-includes/js/wp-util.js    files and find the code $.ajax(
   options ) on line number 100 insert given below code into your file

> ```
> deferred.jqXHR = $.ajax( options ).done( function( response ) {
>   try {
>       response = JSON.parse(response);
>   } catch (Exception) {
>       response = response;
>   }
> ```

Please check your may be resolved.

1. if you Removed constant from db-config.php

> ```
> define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', TRUE);
> define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE);
> define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
> ```

2. Then compress your /wp-includes/js/wp-util.js file code and put your compressed code into /wp-includes/js/wp-util.min.js

> *change your own risk if your update your wordpress version your changed may be lost.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the files were not uploaded via media uploader, they are present in the server but there's no reference to them in your database ([in a little more detail](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/360398/110842)).

In order to fix it, install the [Media Sync plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-sync/). Once it's active, under Media > Media Sync > Scan Files and select the files you want to import by click the checkbox next to them. Make sure also you untick the selectbox *Dry Run (test without making database changes)*.

Then, when the time comes for you to be ready, just click "Import Selected" and you should see something like this

[image: Media Sync import images]

Once it is finished, you can visit Media > Library and you'll see all your imported files there.

Answer (score 3):

Did you ever change the directory of your Wordpress install?

I had a problem with not finding my uploaded images after changing the Wordpress location on my server. In Wordpress, I went to Dashboard-> Settings -> Media and changed the uploads folder in the "Store uploads in this folder" field.

Comment: The question is close to be 5 years of age. I honestly can't remember.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu stores uploads in /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/uploads . So what you need is to have this directory within your wordpress installation. Something like:

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/uploads /var/www/www.mysite.com/wp-uploads
```

(replace mysite.com with your domain, the file should exist) should do the trick.

(Note that I've not tested this with multiple wordpress installations on one server.)

Further note that to make upload work at all (but this wasn't the question), you need to change Settings / Media / Store uploads in this folder to

```
 wp-content/uploads
```

(no leading slash).

Answer (score 2):

check **.htaccess** file in root of wordpress, maybe there is a rule for /uploads directory.
if so, remove it. but be careful and check which plugin did it, so disable the plugin, first.