# Images not showing up in Media Library

Tags: php, wordpress, media

I have the same problem as described in this thread: [Wordpress - Images not showing up in the Media Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438193/wordpress-images-not-showing-up-in-the-media-library) . The only thing is that the solutions described are in that thread is not working for me.

I have tried CHMOD all files including "uploads" and folders/files under that.

Any other suggestions how to solve this?

EDIT: Im able to se the images in Media Library, but not under custom fields and featured images.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try, access the file using your web browser with full URL to it. If you can open using web browser, then there is not issue in permissions or CHMOD. This is to confirm the permission.

Comment: Tried that and I was able to access an image via the full URL.

Comment: Do you have any settings for the image path under ur wordpress CMS?

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean. But under "Settings > Media" I have in "Store uploads in this folder" "wp-content/uploads". Im able to se the images in Media Library, but not under custom fields and featured images.

Comment: It seems to be the theme which is causing this to occure. When I activated the twenty ten theme it worked fine. Any suggestions where to start digg in the code to find the "broken link"? Havent built the theme by myself.