# Images Not Showing On Wordpress Media Library And Chrome Browser

Tags: wordpress, image, google-chrome

Before asking this question, I have tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438193/wordpress-images-not-showing-up-in-the-media-library) and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010725/images-not-showing-up-in-media-library) on this kind of question, but none seemed to work. I have given permissions to the uploads folder as well as wp-content. I disabled all plugins and even changed my themes, yet the problem persisted.

Uploaded images are not showing on Media Library at all, but when I try to edit the image itself, it comes up. Also, whenever I open my blog on **Chrome browsers**, most of the images are not displayed. Surprisingly, accessing the blog on **Edge and Firefox** browsers displayed the images perfectly.

What may be wrong? Is it an error in my html code? Maybe the divs or what?

Please, I've been battling with this issue for months now and I've searched everywhere on the web, even Youtube, but none of the solutions proffered worked at all.

What should I do to address this problem?

**PS: Someone suggested that I make some edit to my .htaccess file. Will this work? This is the .htaccess for wp-content**
[Screenshot showing my .htaccess file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EITfd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, a plugin I was installed, WebP, already made some changes to the .htaccess file under wp-content before I uninstalled it. All I did was just delete the file and everything became good again.

I got this help from a guru at WordPress support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was resolving an error similar to this one and i've found that if your website is hosted in `https` but you've not generated any `SSL` certificate yet chrome might `block` some content from loading (you know the continue but might be a dangerous window before accessing it).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32123906)