# WordPress images disappeared sudenly from Media Library

Tags: wordpress, media-library

This morning, all images from WordPress were gone. The media library is empty and none of the images were opening on the website.

Any idea what this can be?

The images are on the server. I double-checked. But they can’t be found by WordPress.

Comment: There was a new WordPress version released yesterday. This error reported here could be because of that. 
Have you tried checking the `debug.log` file for any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, my MySQL database was corrupted. I fixed it through cPanel and everything went back to normal right away. It took 5 seconds to fix the problem, but 2 hours to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to an incompatible plugin, theme or improper file permissions. Can't tell with limited information.

Did you update WordPress or any other plugin BEFORE this problem?

If so, I would advice you to try [suggested troubleshooting](https://wordpress.com/support/plugins/solve-problems-with-plugins/)

If the problem was caused after a theme or plugin update, you could try to do a rollback and check if issue persists. Sometimes, it can take some time for plugin and theme authors to release an update.

I also found this similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438193/wordpress-images-not-showing-up-in-the-media-library?rq=2) which could help you.